# Why do I got different results when using piped commands in contrast to && concatenated commands in bash?

Tags: bash, datetime, command-line, pipe

I implemented a little python function for current_datetime and inserted it in a bash script.

```
$ current_datetime

2017-08-29 12:01:18.413240
```

Later, I assigned it to a variable

```
$ DT=$(current_datetime)
```

Which I can call

```
$ echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:03:48.213455   #and get a time some seconds later for sure
```

But if I run the next line several times, I get the same results (note the same decimal part of the seconds in **bold**)

```
$ DT=$(current_datetime) | echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:04:42.**544683**


$ DT=$(current_datetime) | echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:04:42.**544683**


$ DT=$(current_datetime) | echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:04:42.**544683**
```

In turn, when I use `&&` instead of `|`, I got the exact time when the `Enter` button is pressed each time.  Why?

```
$ DT=$(current_datetime) && echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:21:**11.564654**


$ DT=$(current_datetime) && echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:21:**13.522406**


$ DT=$(current_datetime) && echo $DT

2017-08-29 12:21:**14.744963**
```

What are the differences between `|` and `&&` in regards of its implementation in the same command line and the exact moment when these are executed?

Comment: One is a pipe, the other is a logical and.    In your first example, it is setting `DT` to a value, and then piping the output to `echo $DT`.   Setting `DT` happens in a subshell, and does not affect the enironment where `echo $DT` runs from, or even the next line is run from.   In the `&&` it runs the first command, which sets `DT`, and, because that did not fail, it executes the second command with `DT` set.

Answer (score 4):

Each command in a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) is executed in its own subshell. This means that the variable assignments don't have any effect.

```
$ FOO=bar | echo $FOO

$ echo $FOO

$
```

Whereas the commands in a [list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) separated by `&&` are executed sequentially, not in a subshell.

```
$ FOO=bar && echo $FOO
bar
$
```

Another way to spawn a subshell is [with parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping).

```
$ (FOO=bar) && echo $FOO

$
```